# How to call model's method from collection in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've been trying to learn backbone.js these days. What I've is a model and a collection. The model has some default properties defined in it which I want to fetch within a collection. This is my code:

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        done : true
    }
});

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : model,  

    pickMe : function () {
        log(this.model.get('done')); //return undefined
    }   
});

var col = new collection();
col.pickMe();
```

How do I call methods defined in my model from collection? Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you calling .get() on your model class? You need an instance of a model to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic setup of Backbone is this :

You have models which are part of collection(s). So here in your setup you have a model constructor `model` and collection constructor `collection`, but you have no models in your collection and if you have any models they will be an array, so your code should be something like this

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        done : true
    }
});

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : model,  

    pickMe : function () {
        for ( i = 0; i < this.models.length; i++ ) {
            log(this.models[i].get('done')); // this prints 'true'
        }
    }   
});

// Here we are actually creating a new model for the collection
var col = new collection([{ name : 'jack' }]); 

col.pickMe();
```

You can check the working jsFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/S8tHk/1/

Comment: Thanks drincheve, it worked. You look like a backbone master :-)

Answer (score 2):

@erturne is correct, you're trying to call a method on your model constructor, not a model instance. That doesn't make sense.

If you really want to define methods on the collection, then @drinchev provides an example of how to iterate through the models in the collection and invoke their methods. Although, the example is rather clunky -- using the built-in iterator methods would be more elegant.

Depending what you're trying to accomplish, you may want to just use the built-in collection iterator methods to invoke methods on each model instead of defining methods on the collection. E.g.:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
      done : true
    }
});

var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Model
});

var col = new Collection([{}, {done : false}, {}]);

col.each(function (model) {
  log(model.get('done'));
});
```

Comment: +1 for using each, but I really thought how to explain that models are an Array object in the collection ;) Each is underscore method and is the way for regular usage .

Comment: "I really thought how to explain that models are an Array object in the collection ;)" -- yes, but why? :) If the OP doesn't understand that a collection is a glorified array, they're even more lost than it appears. And if they're this unfamiliar they're probably going to actually use what you showed in the example. Someone like the OP is probably better off starting out learning to use the collection iterator methods rather than working with the underlying array directly for such a simple use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better attach your model methods to the model itself, not in the collection. So you should have somethings like this:

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        done : true
    },
    pickMe : function () {
        log(this.get('done'));
    }
});

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : model,  
});


var model = collection.get(id)
model.pickMe()
```

Comment: We can If we we want but its not a right way to use Backbone.js.